# Getting number of times user logged in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

Is there a way to know that how many times an user logged into the system( UNIX), with the help of `who` or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `count` of how many times a user logged in,then its not possible through `command-line` IMO....specifically because there is `sudo` option to pretend other user which can fail your logic - *if you have any*

Also, `how many times` needs to have a time bracket (*`from when` till `when`*)..so you need to have an upper time bracket as well from which you want to track down the count.All this would be a mess ideally just to maintain a `count`

If i have to keep track of it, my best guess would be to have a `script` and maintain a `db-table` keeping the `count` of `users` who are logging-in!

Answer (score 2):

you may refer :
[Last command of unix](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_last.htm)

and then you can manipulate the output to count or whatever you waana do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `last`:

```
last | grep ^username| grep 'logged in' | wc -l
```

For example:

```
$ last | grep ^igor | grep 'still logged'
igor     pts/9        astaro       Thu Aug 28 09:55   still logged in
```

It takes information about users' logins from the `wtmp`-database (`/var/log/wtmp`).
That means, that only that entries that are in this database are displayed.
You must bear in mind, that tt is possible, that if a user was logged in for a long time ago, there is no information about this login in it (because of a rotation).

Also, I must note, that the notion of "how many times user is logged in" is a bit vague.
User can have running processes, but not be logged in (or at least not registered in `wtmp`),
user can use `su` and so on.

Using this way you can count number of open terminal sessions of a user:

```
$ ps aux | grep ^igor | fgrep S+ | wc -l
12
```

Comment: thnx for your ans...but this command `last | grep ^username| grep 'logged in' | wc -l` will give the information of user logged in currently.

Comment: @pulse: I think that is the task we are trying to solve, isn't it?

Comment: @IgorChubin : No mate, OP wants to have *count* of how many times you logged in...for eg.say `NoobEditor logged in 15 times from SomeDate till SomeDate` :)

Comment: @pulse : tagging you for above comment of mine...its the same explanation as of your requirement...right?

Comment: @NoobEditor: Then you just need to remove `grep 'logged in'`

Comment: @NoobEditor yes.. i want the count.. removing `grep 'logged in'` also not working...

Comment: @pulse : like i said in my answer...it may not be possible to achieve your goal through `commands` only..you need some kind of script for it!

Comment: @IgorChubin its not working... !!

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to /etc/profile.
When you append a line to a logfile, do not forget housekeeping.
You might want to make a logfile-per-day and delete files older than 10 days.